# How to use tensorflow to implement deconvolution?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to take use of tensorflow to implement fully convolutional network. There is a function

```
tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(value, filter, output_shape, strides, padding, name),
```

which could be used to take bilinear upsampling. However, I am confused as to how to use it? The input is an image with a single channel, and the output is also an image with a single channel, whose size is two times the one of the input. 
I tried to use the function as follows, but got an `IndexError: list index out of range`:

```
  with tf.name_scope('deconv') as scope:
    deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv6, [3, 3, 1, 1], 
        [1, 26, 20, 1], 2, padding='SAME', name=None)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Got it! (assuming input_size = [1, 13, 10,1])

```
with tf.name_scope('deconv') as scope:
    deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input_layer, [3, 3, 1, 1], 
         [1, 26, 20, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name=None)
```

Comment: Could you please throw some light on how exactly is this deconvolution? I have been searching for a bit but I do not see how the `conv2d_transpose` function does deconvolution.

Comment: @U.Muneeb Deconvolution is an (apparently incorrect) name for transposed convolution. See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers

Comment: @U.Muneeb  I also like this site  It uses Theano, but the concepts may help you: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/conv_arithmetic.html